# Как получить url прикрепленного файла изображения в google calendar event

Tags: javascript, google-calendar

Я импортировал события из google календаря и отображаю их на сайте с помощью fullcalendar.

Мне нужно отобразить прикрепленный файл изображения в событии google календаря в popup окне при клике на calendar event на моем сайте.
Я пытался получить url картинки с помощью `$j('#test-img').html(event.attachment[0].fileUrl);`, но при клике меня перенаправляет на страницу ивента в гугл календаре. Остальная информация нормально отображается.

Как можно получить корректный url картинки?

```
$j('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyCD7ju2cVMfoM-yLL5IsH3fG9SDUOexjH0',
    events:'jetme6103iige9dqvd7pejpt34@group.calendar.google.com',
    firstDay: 1,
    timeFormat: 'MMMM',
    height: "auto",

    eventClick: function(event) {
        PopUpShow();
        $j('#title').html(event.title);
        $j('#start').html(moment(event.start).format("DD MMMM YYYY"));
        $j('#test-desc').html(event.description);
        $j('#test-img').html(event.attachment[0].fileUrl);
        console.log(event);
        return false;
    },
    loading: function(bool) {
        $j('#loading').toggle(bool);
    },
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        var dataToFind = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        $j("td[data-date='" + dataToFind + "']").addClass('activeDay');
    }
});
```